# Get all images and put them in a div

Tags: jquery, image

I like to create a div around all images in an article so by example:

```
img 1
img 2
img 3
```

Outcome must be

```
<div id="allimg">
img 1
img 2
img 3
</div>
```

Comment: will the images have a particular class? where will the images be located? What if there is text between the images?

Comment: More of an idea of the surrounding markup and structure would lead to a better variety of answers.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery provides the very useful [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll) function for you:

```
$('img').wrapAll('<div id="allImg"></div>');
```

Comment: interesting - I see that appears to reparent all of the wrapped elements even if they weren't siblings before.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
$images = $('.articleWrapper img'); // get all the images into a jQuery object
$('#allimg').append($images.clone()); // add a copy of them to your div
$images.remove(); // remove the originals from the DOM
```

Comment: why clone them? If you just append them, they'll get moved. `$('#allimg').append('.articleWrapper img')` would do the same thing (but would be faster and maintain all events and data attached to the images).

Answer (score 0):

Without assuming anything about your page layout:

```
var $i = $('img').first();             // Find the first image:
var $d = $('<div>').insertBefore($i);  // Create the new div before the first image
$('img').appendTo($d);                 // Move all images into `$d`
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/54kQk/

**EDIT** it turns out this is more or less the implementation of `.wrapAll()`.